# NextJS 13 cache invalidation and multiple instances of node?

Tags: caching, next.js, pm2

I have a Next JS app that I under multiple instances of in PM2 cluster mode. I'm about to upgrade the app to Next JS and take advantage of Server components. The caching is very compelling and I plan to use a webhook to invalidate the cache when things change in the backend API.

But how does the next js caching work? Is it local to the process running the app? And when using PM2 in cluster mode, how can I be sure that it clear the cache tag on in all running instances?